# Why won't my ascx file pick up my code behind properties?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, view, code-behind

My web app is a solution built on top of another solution. The base solution is meant to be a platform for multiple products. For the most part, this works fine, but weird things happen when I create product specific views.

I am using `ViewUserControl<SomeViewModel>` for my code behind class. In my code behind, I have access to `this.Model` and all the other goodies I'd expect from this class. But in my ascx file, I get red squiggley lines when I try to access `this.Model` or other properties defined in `ViewUserControl`. I also get red squiggley lines when I try to access properties defined directly in my code behind.

What's more interesting is, I don't get any real errors from this. The view renders just fine at run time and does not give me any build errors. But my ascx file **thinks** there will be errors. If I create **the exact same view** in the platform namespaces, it works fine. No red squiggles.

I find this to be really annoying. It's not a show stopper by any means, but if I'm going to be using an IDE with intellisense and all that jazz, I'd sure like it to work properly, and pick up the properties that are supposed to be there.

Has anyone else run into this? Do you know of a way to fix this?

Thanks!

**Edit**

It was requested that I post some code. Here's the code behind:

```
namespace MyProject.MyProduct.Web.Views
{
    public class EditSearch : ViewUserControl<SearchResultsViewModel>
    {
        public bool IsSearchTypeA()
        {
            ...............
        }

        public bool IsSearchTypeB()
        {
            ...............
        }
    }
}
```

And here's my ascx:

```
<% 
    if (!this.IsSearchTypeB())
    { 
        string categoryPageTitle = this.Model.SearchWidgetParameters.Search.CategoryPageTitle;
        string categoryPageUrl = this.Model.SearchWidgetParameters.Search.Filters.CategoryPageUrl;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(categoryPageUrl))
        {
            %> <div id="coid_website_backtoCategoryPageLink"> <%

            string tocGuid = this.Model.SearchWidgetParameters.Search.Filters.TocGuid;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tocGuid))
            {
                categoryPageUrl += "?guid=" + tocGuid;
            }

            var backToLink = new HyperLink();

            if (this.IsSearchTypeA())
            {
                backToLink.Text = "Edit Search";
            }
            else
            {
                backToLink.Text = "Back to " + TranslatedHtmlTextWriter.Translate(categoryPageTitle);
            }

            backToLink.NavigateUrl = TransactionOperations.AddContextToUrl(categoryPageUrl.StartsWith("/Browse/") ? categoryPageUrl : "/Browse/" + categoryPageUrl,
                                                                            WebsiteTransitionType.Default, // Requested: CategoryPage
                                                                            TransactionOperations.DefaultContextData);
            backToLink.RenderControl(this.Writer);
            %>
                </div>
            <%
        } 
    }
%>
```

**Edit**

For those of you who are telling me that ASP.NET MVC cannot or does not use code behind, I'm sorry but this is horse hockey. This project has existed for years and there is a widely used product that runs on it. My product is only just recently jumping onto the Platform. The Platform solution uses code behind all over the place, and it works fine. In fact, it works fine at runtime in my product's solution as well, I just have the problem that my ascx file doesn't seem to know about my code behind. Furthermore, `ViewUserControl` is a `System.Web.MVC` class. Are you still going to tell me that code behind isn't used in ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: You shouldn't be using a code behind with ASP.NET MVC.  Can you post some code?

Comment: That confuses me greatly. If don't use code behind, then how would I access properties of my model? The code behind is where I specify that my model is of a certain type. I don't know how else I would get at the properties.

Comment: What version of MVC are you using? I am using MVC 3 and I dont see any code behind file. What I would call "code behind" is the Controller and the Model.

Comment: You should specify the model type in the inheritance attribute of the <%@Page line... Or <%@Control.  Like this

Comment: Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<HomePageViewModel>  Sorry, can't handle that it posts on enter now-a-days

Comment: @Davis I think it generated a codebehind in the earlier versions of ASP.NET MVC. But that has been fixed.

Comment: MVC doesn't use code behind you are simply running WebForm pages in an MVC project without using any of the MVC features ergo a Controller.  You can do this because MVC runs on top of ASP.NET the same way WebForms does, but it doesn't mean you are doing it right.

Comment: Ok, David, that's why `ViewUserControl` is a `System.Web.MVC` class. Sure.

Comment: @ullmark: This didn't work. I created a model called MaxwellDocument and I inserted `<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<Cobalt.GTLRMaxwell.Web.Models.MaxwellDocument>" %>` into my control, but `this.Model` doesn't appear in my intellisense dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are developing MVC you cannot use code behind. Instead, what do you think about adding this at the top of your .acsx file:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="Namespace.Model" %>
```

Then you can access everything you have in there without so much complication.

Comment: Cannot use code behind? That doesn't make any sense. The Platform solution uses code behind all over the place, and it works. So why doesn't mine?

Comment: Also, how would that import help me with accessing properties of the model? My model is of a specific type, and I need specific properties of that model.

Comment: I tried your suggestion using my namespace and model but I still don't have access to my model or its properties.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET MVC does not use code behind.  It sounds like you are mixing ASP.NET MVC and ASP.NET WebForm pages.

I suggest you take a look at http://www.asp.net/mvc.  It has some great tutorials on getting started with MVC and how it works.

Comment: This project has existed on ASP.NET MVC for years. I don't need to get the project started. Thanks.

Comment: @Sumo, MVC runs on top of ASP.NET the same way WebForms does so the two can co-exist and run in the same project as it appears you are doing.  I wasn't trying to suggest you need to get the project started but that you appear to have an misunderstanding of how MVC works. I came to this conclusion because you appear to be missing a Controller which is the C in MVC.

Comment: I'm not missing a controller but thanks for assuming.

The purpose of the code behind is to specify the type of model and add some helper methods. It is my controller that renders this view. How else would I get to the view? And why is the `ViewUserControl` a `Sytem.Web.MVC` class if it's not supposed to be used with MVC?